# How to display all posts of specific custom post types, including normal posts?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to display all posts of 2 specific custom post type (`causes` and `evenements`), but I also want to include all normal posts. Here's my query :

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'causes', 'evenements', 'post' ),
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Unfortunately, this only returns normal posts.

When I use this query, it shows all posts of `causes` and `evenements` custom posts :

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'causes', 'evenements' ),
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
```

How can I display all posts of `causes`, `evenements` and `post` post types?

I can't use `any` value for the `post_type` because I also have other custom post types that I don't want to include in my query.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: this behaviour is weird, did you try with query_posts n get_post ?

Comment: it seems to work with `get_posts`, any idea why it's different?

Comment: nope i cant see a valid reason behind this

Comment: ok thanks for your help, I will use `get_post()`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use this plugin Ultimate "[Category Excluder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/)"

It is simple to use and the ui provided is user friendly.